# Is there a way to wait for the DOM to update in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

If I have something like the following

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <input *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [name]="'input_' + i" [(ngModel)]="item" myValidationAttribute>
</form>
```

and I have a function that updates items and I need to wait form the form to update before submitting the form

```
updateAndSubmit() {
  this.items = newItems;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
      // Do stuff with valid form
    }
  });
}
```

Is using setTimeout like this the preferred way of waiting for the DOM refresh or is there something along the line of fixture.whenStable() used in unit testing?

setTimeout just doesn't feel right, like it is a dirty hack.

Here is a StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pv4tyb

Comment: `setTimeout` is not only about delaying something in a given number of milliseconds. It appends the callback to the end of the js event queue. So other things can get executed before the callback runs. I don't think this is a dirty hack but the proper way. BTW, I don't think you need to wait for the view before submitting the data as the data is already there in memory.

Comment: This is for testing purposes? If so, I would recommend making that more obvious by including it in the title and in the tags.

Comment: This is not about testing

Comment: Submitting the form without the setTimeout submits and empty form as the inputs have not rendered yet. I have tried to simplify the form for the sake of the question but in my real world use I want to form to render so that the validation can be run.

Comment: I think what you want to do in this case is be using reactive forms instead of template driven forms. you're stuck relying on change detection to run for the directives to instantiate and your validation to run, if you were using a reactive form, you wouldn't have this strange dependency. In the template driven form case though, your only solution is to either use a timeout or to inject your validation directive and run it manually

Comment: But reactive forms turns you relatively simple template driven app with minimal easy to follow code into a giant amount of code generating forms objects that need to be bound to the template. I am willing to live with the setTimeout as it is only needed in one scenario where if the grid is filtered the filter needs to be removed to make rows that are not onscreen show up to get them validated. Using reactive forms I would still need to regenerate the form objects for the whole data set to validate the currently filtered entries.

Comment: Probably you can subscribe to **statusChanges** on the form instance and submit when form is valid, this way you will not need to put any timeout.Subscription should be ones on first click. between the time to wait for validation submit can be made disabled after first click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Antediluvian said, this is not a hack, it's about putting the callback onto the end of the event queue, i.e. making sure that the code in the callback doesn't run in the current event loop, but it the next one or later.

That said, if you find yourself doing something like this, and need to specify a delay in the setTimeout, then you have a problem, because it's unlikely that the delay that you use in development will work for all clients.

In this case, the simple setTimeout that you are using should be fine, and AFAIK, is "the way that it's done".

I understand that your actual code is more complex, but based on this example, consider that you don't need to push that extra value through the form - you can just get the value of the form, and modify that directly (or a copy of the form value) to produce the value that you use (for, say, posting to an API).

Comment: it's a little bit of a hack to me, though not an especially dirty or egregious one.  He's setting a timeout to force angular to run validation on some inputs. It's creating a hidden dependency that could be a source of confusing bugs, instead of explicitly running his validation in code

Comment: I am happy to stick with the setTimeout then

Answer (score 0):

to me, this is 100% a reactive forms use case instead of template driven forms:

```
<form [formGroup]="itemsFa">
  <input *ngFor="let item of itemsFa.controls; index as i" [name]="'input_' + i" [formControlName]="i">
</form>


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.itemsFa = this.fb.array([]);
}

updateAndSubmit() {
  this.itemsFa.clear();
  newItems.forEach(item => {
    const fc = new FormControl(item, [myValidator]); // convert validation directive to validator fn
    this.itemsFa.push(fc)
  });
  if (this.itemsFa.valid) {
    // Do stuff with valid form
  }
}
```

blitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5rhgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Maybe for this simplified example but the code to generate the reactive forms for the  real world example would be very much more complicated than the template driven style we are using.

Comment: to each their own, it's a trade off, i prefer the bit of extra code for the expressiveness and flexibility reactive forms bring

Comment: I find template form more flexible especially with cross field validation where the validation of one field changes depending on the value of another field. You need to continually rebuild your reactive form objects vs using input decorators on your validation attributes.

Comment: I would use a group level validator for a cross field validation in a reactive form rather than constantly clearing / adding validators or rebuilding my form controls

Comment: Getting back to the initial question of how to wait for the DOM to update in Angular it wouldn't matter what type of forms we are using. The requirement is if a field that has been filtered out of view is invalid, we need to clear the filter and have the invalid field shown with focus on the first invalid field. We would still need to use setTimeout with reactive forms for the focus on the first invalid field even if we could get the form validity synchronously.

Comment: i will typically use a directive to auto focus on a field due to the issues you're mentioning of needing the fields to render before you can focus on them, and it typically accepts a boolean value to determine if it should autofocus or not when it instantiates, so you'd really just need to figure out which form control or index you need to focus on and use that, which all can happen synchronously / without timeouts